# Can Pain read minds with his Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

Can Akatsuki's leader Pain (Nagato) read minds with the ocular powers of his Rinnegan?

Comment: what gives you the impression that he could? have you seen anything that would suggest he could?

Comment: Are you referring to the [Human Path](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Human_Path)?

Comment: Yeah, I think he is referring to the Human Path.

Answer (score 3):

**Source:**
[NARUTO WIKIA](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Six_Paths_Technique)

The Rinnegan user is bestowed with the Six Paths power. And weirdly, there are seven paths:

> **1. Deva Path:** 
>   Allows one to manipulate attractive and repulsive forces.
>
> **2. Asura Path:**
>   Grants the user mechanized limbs, weaponry and armor.
>
> **3. Human Path:**
>   Gives the ability to remove a soul and so, read a person's mind.
>
> **4. Animal Path:**
>   Lets the user summon a wide variety of creatures.
>
> **5. Preta Path:**
>   Which can absorb all forms of chakra, including most ninjutsu.
>
> **6. Naraka Path:**
>   Through which one can summon and control the *King Of Hell*.
>
> **7. Outer Path:**
>   Through which one rules over both life and death.

As Nagato was crippled, he used the Outer Path to manipulate the six corpses (the Pain who fought Naruto & Jiraiya), and channeled other Paths through the Chakra Rods.

And so, by using the Human Path, Pain can read other people's minds.